# Test connection to database, return true or false

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This question seems simple but I can't do it.
in fact my code test the connection to mysql database and return only true if it connect or false if not, 
I used jquery and Ajax to do that, but unfortunately, I couldn't get the result.
my html page have input filed to supply database information and one button to test connection, the result will be displayed on the page (true or false).

ajax call:

```
$.post(

        'php/test_dbconnect.php',
         {
            db_host: $("#db_host").val(),
            db_name: $("#db_name").val(),
            db_user: $("#db_user").val(),
            db_password: $("#db_password").val()
         },

        function(data){
            $("#result").val(data);
        },
        'text',
    );
```

test_dbconnect.php

```
$db_host = $_POST['db_host'];
$db_name = $_POST['db_name'];
$db_user = $_POST['db_user'];
$db_password = $_POST['db_password'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name );

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

$status = "Failed";    

} else {
    $status = "Success";
}
mysqli_close($conn);

echo $status;
```

when connection to database is not possible, ajax don't return 'False', and the page displayed html alert.
response displayed:

Comment: Check the response of ajax in the network tab. In failure, it should return 500 error. Is that the case?

Comment: The ajax should not return 'false' because you are echo'ing out "Failed" or "Success" from the request. So ajax will be a successful action. Unless I'm misunderstanding your english, as your question ends abruptly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your replys,
in fact my problem was in the ajax return when the connection to database fails, it return html reponse, at the end of this reponse it said 'Failed'.
so to resolve his issu, I make a test of returned value if it contains word 'Failed'.

```
$.post(

        'php/test_dbconnect.php',
         {
            db_host: $("#db_host").val(),
            db_name: $("#db_name").val(),
            db_user: $("#db_user").val(),
            db_password: $("#db_password").val()
         },

        function(data){
            if (data.indexOf('Failed') != -1) {
                data="Failed";
            } 
            $("#conStatus").text(data);
            $('#conStatus').show();
        },
        'text',
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP docs says:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
  ...
}
```

Try to check mysqli_connect result instead of mysqli_connect_errno.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code; review this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp):

```
<?php 

$host = "host";
$user = "root";
$pass = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

if(!$conn) {
    echo "Connection Failed";
} else {
    echo "Connection Successful";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is potentially dangerous but the following code works. The only difference is it dies when gets the error!

**AJAX:**

```
    <script>
         $.post({
             url: 'php/test_dbconnect.php',
             data:{
                db_host: $("#db_host").val(),
                db_name: $("#db_name").val(),
                db_user: $("#db_user").val(),
                db_password: $("#db_password").val()             
             },
             success: function(data){
                       $("#result").val(data);
             },
             dataType: 'text'
         });
    </script>
```

**test_dbconnect.php**

```
        $db_host = $_POST['db_host'];
        $db_name = $_POST['db_name'];
        $db_user = $_POST['db_user'];
        $db_password = $_POST['db_password'];

        $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name );
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Failed');
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);

        die('Success');
```